# Variable function call in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm designing a tool which recursively identifies upstream pathways in a vector river network.  I'd like to be able to truncate the search if the cumulative path cost passes a test which is defined by the user, and I'm not sure whether this is possible.  Below is an example of the sort of thing I'd like to do:

```
def test1(value):
    if value > 1: return True
    else: return False

def test2(value):
    if value % 4: return True
    else: return False

def main(test):
    for i in range(20):
        if SPECIFIEDTEST(i):
            print i
            break

main(test1)
```

I know exec() can be used for this purpose but I also understand this is frowned upon?  Is there another, better method for passing a function to another function?

Comment: Where's the user input coming from?

Comment: Functions are first-class entities in python: you can simply pass a function to another function, or bind a local variable to the function and call it that way.  So I'm confused by what you're confused about, e.g., did you mean you're looking for something like `f = {'test1':test1, 'test2':test2}[key]`?  (after which `f(i)` calls the desired function)

Comment: `def test1(value): return value > 1`, etc. You rarely need to use the actual literals `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building a dictionary for this is unnecessary, as functions can be passed in as parameters to other functions. Simply pass the function into `main()`

```
def test1(value):
    if value > 1: return True
    else: return False

def test2(value):
    if value % 4: return True
    else: return False

# using test1 as the default input value...
def main(test = test1):
    for i in range(20):
        if test(i):
            print i
            break

main(test1)
# prints 2

main(test2)
# prints 1
```

Comment: Given the poster mentions user-definition and asks about `exec` I'm assuming string input is involved; that's why a `dict` is needed.

Comment: Sorry, this was a really basic question.  I simply wasn't sure whether it was possible to pass a function to another function directly.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tzaman You're right, that's a good assumption. In the case of user inputs as strings, a dictionary would be a good fit. Either way, a variable holding a function is still being passed in.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a dictionary that maps function names to the actual functions, and use that:

```
tests = {'test1': test1, 'test2': test2}
if tests[specifiedtest](i):
    ...
```